# PMPRO before checkout hook or filter

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I am using a **Paid Membership pro** plugin in WordPress everything is working fine and there were no issues at all before this I have customized many functionalities with the help of the following link.

> https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/hooks-filters/

Now, I want to execute my custom function **Before Checkout** as I have done this but I executed custom code after checkout with the help of following hook.

```
add_action("pmpro_after_checkout", "function_name", 10, 1);
```

I am trying to call my custom function before checkout but can't find the proper hook or filter to do so I am trying the following hook to achieve what I want.

```
add_action("pmpro_before_checkout", "function_name", 10, 1);
```

I just need a hook or filter which can executed my function before the checkout.

Answer (score 0):

This is old but may be helpful to someone in the future.  For **Before** Checkout, you can try
add_action("pmpro_checkout_before_processing", "function_name", 10, 1);

The documentation isn't very good but you can find it [here](https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/hook/pmpro_checkout_before_processing/).

For **After** Checkout, you can try:
add_action("pmpro_after_checkout","callback",10,2);
It accepts the following parameters: int $user_id, MemberOrder object $morder

The documentation is slightly better and you can find it [here](https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/hook/pmpro_after_checkout/).